# Determine UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I have UIButton in every UITableViewCell. How can I check in which cell is button pressed?

Button is added in custom class of UITableViewCell (not in cellForRowAtIndexPath).

How it works: I have thumbUp in every UITableViewCell (grouped Tableview) and I need to know for which cell is thumbUp pressed. I can see max 2 cells at a time (because cell height is 400). I tried increment counter every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called. It works for 1st cell but when I scroll down and cellForRow is called for second cell, counter is raised, but thumbUp button of first cell is still visible and if I press that thumbUp, it will be like 2nd cell thumbUp is pressed. Hope you understand.

Need help !!! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath =
        [self.myTableView
         indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]];
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

    // Do something with row index
}
```

or give tag to every `UIButton` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

and get cell object

```
 - (IBAction)buttonWasPressed:(id)sender
    {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sender.tag];
    }
```